# What is the ranking impact of two domains on two different ip address for the same site

Tags: seo, ranking

I have a client that has an ecommerce website on xcart and a blog on a subdomain but on a different wordpress site and server (separate ip addresses) .
What is the impact on Google SEO Ranking and should I encourage the client to move the blog to the same ip address?

Fictitious Example:

www.clientxcart.com (ecommerce site) ip 149.320.23.4

www.blog.clientxcart.com (blog) ip 132.32.23.2

Comment: You better go for a sub-domain it would have the same impact on your ranking

Answer (score 2):

Depends what you mean by "Same".

If you're copying a site word-for-word, picture-for-picture from site to site, then there is a good chance that google won't index both copies of the site.

You're better off to use rel-canonical on one copy of the site where the href points to the original copy of the site.

Here's some videos from google's head of spam himself, Matt Cutts:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mQZY7EmjbMA

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LgbOibxkEQw

They may help you answer your question, but it all depends on what you mean by "same".

Comment: Each of the two sites have different content but they both are part of the company. One is for ecommerce (xcart) the other for blog artices (wordpress blog).  But they both have the same domain name except the blog is on a subdomain.  Each have different ip addresses (but linked on the sites to each other).

Comment: Then in your case there should be no impact SEO wise unless either computer with one of the two IP addresses you deal with has major connection downtime (for example: takes 1 or 2 seconds to load a page as opposed to the usual 1/2 second)

Comment: Thanks Mike....  Would it be a better strategy to have both domain and sub domain on the same server to increase traffic to one rather than both?  Would this increase their overall ranking?

Answer (score 1):

There is no impact what-so-ever.

There could be an argument made to consolidate both sites into one domain (e.g. ditch the subdomain). Google considers blog.clientxcart.com and clientxcart.com to be two entirely different sites, so your available search authority is spread between two sites instead of one.

But yea, as for the IP situation you detailed - it has no impact.

Comment: Thanks Nick...my focus was on seo value and most of the articles and advice I am getting says "it is not suppose to matter but it often does with tremendous consequences"